# plot.ts - change font size of labels & axis.labels

Tags: r, time-series, r-base-graphics

When I plot a time series (f.e. cardox from astsa-package) I am not able to change the fontsize of labels and axis.labels:

```
library(astsa)
class(cardox)
plot(cardox)
plot(cardox,cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=0.5,cex=0.5)
```

The plots look the same, the fontsize didn't change, despite the different cex-attributes.

What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `plot.ts` does not allow one to pass these parameters as arguments. Instead, try setting the parameters of interest with `par()`. See the help file `?par` for more details on which parameters can be set.

```
library(astsa)
class(cardox)
par(cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=0.5,cex=0.5) # set cex with par()
plot(cardox)
```

You might also consider `astsa::tsplot()`:

```
library(astsa)
class(cardox)
par(cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=0.5,cex=0.5) # set cex with par()
astsa::tsplot(cardox)
```